# web.config custom ConfigurationSection and unnecessary verbosity

Tags: c#, .net, web-config, configuration-files

Unless I am doing something wrong, the way I am supposed to use ConfigurationSection, ConfigurationElement and ConfigurationElementCollection, would require me to format my configuration section like so:

```
<serviceAuthorization>
    <credentials>
        <login username="system" password="password" mode="include">
            <services>
                <service type="AxeFrog.Mobile.Service.Security.AuthenticationService, AxeFrog.Mobile.Service" />
                <service type="AxeFrog.Mobile.Service.Security.AnotherService, AxeFrog.Mobile.Service" />
            </services>
        </login>
        <login username="test" password="pass" mode="exclude" />
    </credentials>
</serviceAuthorization>
```

I would much prefer if I had a bit more say in the format. I would like to format my section like this:

```
<serviceAuthorization>
    <login username="system" password="password" mode="include">
        <service type="AxeFrog.Mobile.Service.Security.AuthenticationService, AxeFrog.Mobile.Service" />
        <service type="AxeFrog.Mobile.Service.Security.AnotherService, AxeFrog.Mobile.Service" />
    </login>
    <login username="test" password="pass" mode="exclude" />
</serviceAuthorization>
```

Is there a way I can get the XML of the configuration section and just read it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement [`System.Configuration.IConfigurationSectionHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.iconfigurationsectionhandler.aspx) and configure it:

```
<section name="serviceAuthorization" type="[your-type]"/>
```

Then you get your entire `section` as `XmlNode` and can parse your custom schema.

**edit**: this is deprecated. here is one [*new way*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx) to do it.

Comment: As I understand it, IConfigurationSectionHandler has been deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do, for example:

```
string docName=System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Web.config");
XmlDocument configDoc = new XmlDocument();
configDoc.Load(docName);
```

and then work from `configDoc`.

Comment: I am aware of that route; I was just hoping for something a little less crude.